# Multiplying a quantity, estimated to 2 significant digits, by a constant

Tags: error-analysis

If I were to multiply a quantity known to 2 significant digits by a 3-digit number, would it be reasonable to express the result using only 2 significant digits.

Comment: ......yes......

Comment: Is there uncertainty in your constant?

Comment: I didn't consider this situation, but what if the constant exhibits some uncertainty, like an uncertainty of about 10%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the original quantity is known to 2 significant digits it would be highly **unreasoanble** to express any multiple of it with more than 2 significant digits.